# Can't install android sdk on ubuntu

Tags: android, sdk

I want to install Android studio. I've downloaded Android studio and installed it using [Install Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html). When I run `./studio.sh` it opens the window and says that Android SDK is installed and doesn't let me to install it (the checkbox doesn't work).
[image: Android SDK (Installed)]

So I click next and finish and the it says:

> Nothing to do!
>   SDK tools directory is missing

So I click Finish and then Start a new Android Studio project and says:

> Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted.

Then I Open SDK Manager and I can't do anything there (Shown in the image bellow)

[image]

If I click the Edit button, I have the same messages as above.

I've also checked the connection in HTTP Proxy tab and there's no problem in connecting to dl.google.com or any other website.

What should I do?

Comment: Does `/home/vmoh/Android/Sdk` exist on your machine? The install wizard seems to think that the Android SDK is installed already.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes it exists and it first was empty. then i downloaded sdk tools and extracted it there but didn't help. then i removed the whole folder and again didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although proxy settings were correctly set but still the problem was with the connection. I set up a VPN using openconnect and tried again and everything worked as expected